# Android MediaPlayer State Changes

Tags: android, android-activity, media-player, activity-lifecycle

I hope this isn't a dumb question, as I am rather new to Android, but I'm having trouble handling the state changes with MediaPlayer. The mediaplayer works fine while on the screen, and it continues to play the sound while the screen isn't visible, but when I return to the activity and try to stop the mediaplayer, it won't stop. I don't see anyway to get a streamID from mp, which I could save and restore on onPause and onResume. There must be something simple I'm missing. Here's some snippets of what I have so far:

```
    public class Noise extends Activity {
       public MediaPlayer mp;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layour.main);

        Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        Button stopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.noise);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){
                 playSoundLoop();
                 }
               });

        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v){
                 stopSound();
                 }
               });
       }

    public void playSoundLoop(){
         mp.setLooping(true);
         mp.start();
     }

    public void stopSound(){
         mp.pause();
         //Had originally tried mp.stop, mp.reset, mp.prepare, but that didn't work any better
     }
```

}

Comment: Is your activity being destroyed? Add a log statement in your onCreate to see if you are creating a new instance of MediaPlayer. Seems odd though, because if that was the case, the call to pause() should through an illegal state exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're deallocating the original MediaPlayer instance. So, when you leave the activity and return, `onCreate()` is called again, and you end up with two instances until memory pressure causes the old one to get released.

The simple solution is release it when your activity leaves the foreground, eg:

```
@Override
    onPause() {
    mp.release();
    super.onPause();
}
```

However, if you want your music to continue playing in the background, you need to move the MediaPlayer reference somewhere outside the Activity lifecycle - probably into a service.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the quick response. I just set it up to pause and release the mediaplayer onPause, and now everything seems to work OK, but I was hoping to have the music play in the background. So you're right, I think I need a service to do that. I thought it seemed way to easy to have it play in the background. ;)

Comment: Ha, yes. MediaPlayer's a bit of a pain in my opinion. You might find [this wrapper](https://gist.github.com/1029568) I wrote useful if you continue with it. It provides access to the current state, which seems to be sorely missing feature.

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I will keep that in my arsenal. In my testing, I switched to soundpool, which gives me more options for looping (since I want to loop a certain  number of times based on user input), but it doesn't seem a whole lot better than mediaplayer. It works, but there isn't a whole lot of documentation out there for it. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I was trying to implement States myself and just found your wrapper - this looks really well written!